# What is the equivalent of branch reset operator ("?|") found in php(pcre) in C#?

Tags: c#, php, regex, branch, reset

The following regular expression will match "Saturday" or "Sunday" : `(?:(Sat)ur|(Sun))day`

But in one case backreference 1 is filled while backreference 2 is empty and in the other case vice-versa.

PHP (pcre) provides a nice operator "?|" that circumvents this problem. The previous regex would become `(?|(Sat)ur|(Sun))day`. So there will not be empty backreferences.

Is there an equivalent in C# or some workaround ?

Comment: You could use `(?:(Sat(?=ur)|Sun(?!ur))(?:ur)?)day` instead. :)

Comment: @Gumbo why having Sun not followed by "ur"? The regular expression is a bit complicated...

Comment: otherwise, `Sunurday` could be matched. Which is a bit like the mistake I made (which _you_ pointed out :))

Comment: Otherwise it would also match `Sunurday`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

.NET doesn't support the branch-reset operator, but it does support named groups, and it lets you reuse group names without restriction (something no other flavor does, AFAIK).  So you could use this:

```
(?:(?<abbr>Sat)ur|(?<abbr>Sun))day
```

...and the abbreviated name will be stored in `Match.Groups["abbr"]`.

Comment: Yes, that's the way to go (in case of a regex). Neat.

Comment: Perl lets you reuse named groups in the same pattern. There’s no restriction. That also allows you to get back a list of named groups that matched.

Comment: with PCRE, you can use the `(?J)` modifier (must be placed at the first position in the pattern) that allows the use of named groups with the same name. (This is a once and for all option, you can't unset it after).

Comment: This answer has been added to the [Stack Overflow Regular Expression FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496), under "Groups".

Comment: Python's [regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/#notes-on-named-capture-groups) allows reusing group names, but of-course it also knows [branch reset](https://pypi.org/project/regex/#branch-reset) operator.

Answer (score 4):

should be possible to concat backref1 and backref2.
 As one of each is always empty and a string concat with empty is still the same string...

with your regex `(?:(Sat)ur|(Sun))day` and replacement `$1$2`
 you get `Sat` for `Saturday` and `Sun` for `Sunday`.

```
 regex (?:(Sat)ur|(Sun))day
 input    | backref1 _$1_ | backref2 _$2_ | 'concat' _$1$2_
 ---------|---------------|---------------|----------------
 Saturday | 'Sat'         | ''            | 'Sat'+'' = Sat
 Sunday   | ''            | 'Sun'         | ''+'Sun' = Sun
```

instead of reading backref1 or backref2 just read both results and concat the result.

Comment: i'd prefer having the results directly without any manipulation on the input string (like branch-reset operator).

Comment: @Stephan I don't understand your comment? I don't think I did manipulation on the input string. I just pointed out that you could concat group1 and group2 from the regex result with no changes on the regex.

Comment: @bw_üezi can you edit your answer with a detailed sample code because i still don't understand your solution.

Comment: +1 this seems so much better than making the regular expression more complicated just to get the desired value out in one back reference.

Comment: @juharr thanks for understanding my [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) solution ;-)

Comment: @bw_üezi I'm a big KISS fan, the band and the principle.

Comment: @bw_üzei well, your solution is simple but it requires two steps.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the branch-reset operator:

```
(?|foo(bar)|still(life)|(like)so)
```

That will only set group one no matter which branch matches.

Comment: And here I thought StackOverflow was the place to look for quality, not quantity in answers.