# How can I force two patterns to capture to the same group in regEx

Tags: .net, regex, regex-group

I have to parse a string, formatted as`!info1!info2!`, and `info2` is optional.

I am trying to capture, using a regular expression, `info1` and `info2` if needed.

I came up with the following pattern:

```
!([^!]*?)!(.*?)!|!(.*?)!
```

It works, but I am not satisfied with the results:

```
!foo!bar! -> Group1: foo Group2:bar
!foo!     -> Group3: foo
(https://regex101.com/r/D9d6YP/1)
```

In both expression, `foo` means the same thing, and is to be process in the same way afterwards. I would like to capture it in the same group, whether or not there is a second group.

I have tried to use named capture groups, but it seems like they can't be reused

```
!(?<info1>[^!]*?)!(?<info2>.*?)!|!(?<info1>.*?)!
```

fails with the error message 'a sub-pattern name must be unique.

Is there any way to capture different patterns in the same group?

Comment: Pleae supply an example string without the optional part.

Comment: Your regex101 link seems to imply that you are using a PCRE pattern? Is that correct?

Comment: No, it's .NET, the flavor in regex101 is just the default one.

Comment: So no branch resets, but https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5377782/what-is-the-equivalent-of-branch-reset-operator-found-in-phppcre-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use an optional non-capturing group to merge both alternatives into a single branch:

```
!([^!]*)!(?:([^!]*)!)?
         ^^^        ^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9XLywJ/1)

**Details**:

- `!` - a `!`
- `([^!]*)` - Group 1: any 0+ chars other than `!`
- `!` - a `!`
- `(?:([^!]*)!)?` - an optional non-capturing group (its result is not stored in memory, no ID is assigned to it) matching 1 or 0 occurrences of

  - `([^!]*)`  - Group 2: any 0+ chars other than `!`
  - `!` - a `!`

Comment: The pasted code is different from the Regex Demo, demo has \n.

I hope the regex101 site is up for ever.

Comment: @ClownMan Of course it is different. It is not a *proof* the regex works, it showcases how the regex will behave with real life strings. When you use the regex in C#, they are *stand-alone*, while in the regex demo, I use a *single multiline* string. Since `[^!]` matches any char but `!`, it matches a newline, and confuses a person who tests the regex against the *lines*.