# Python alternative for a branch reset operator ("?|") used in pcre?

Tags: python, regex

I would like to use the following regular expression in python and it was successfully tested with PCRE. Switching to python is giving me an error.

```
^password\s+sufficient\s+pam_unix\.so\s(?|.*?(remember=(?P<val>\d*))|()())?
```

My input file is

```
password    sufficient pam_unix.so sha512 shadow use_authtok
password    sufficient pam_unix.so sha512 shadow use_authtok remember=2 
#password    sufficient pam_unix.so sha512 shadow use_authtok remember=10
```

I'm expecting two matches with group_1 and group_2 each.

```
Match1  password    sufficient pam_unix.so 
Group1  empty string
Group2  empty string
Match2  password    sufficient pam_unix.so sha512 shadow use_authtok remember=2
Group1  remember=2
Group2  2
```

It seems that python is not supporting branch resets, is there any alternative?

Comment: Not a duplicate but perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/q/5377782/14637 has some useful pointers.

Comment: Just install the [PyPi regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) (`pip install regex` in your console) and then use `import regex as re` and keep the current code as is.

Comment: Are you using `.findall()`? If yes, then [this](https://ideone.com/RAxPYa) would give your expected result, not?

Comment: ```import regex as re``` worked for me thanks